# В Wpf не работает привязка

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь привязать коллекцию картинок к листбоксу. Код:

Модель:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Media;
using System.IO;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Bind
{
    class MyImage:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyImage( string path, string descriptionTop, string descriptionBottom )
        {
            this.img = new Image();
            this.img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path));

            this.descriptionTop = descriptionTop;
            this.descriptionBottom = descriptionBottom;
            this.FullPath = path;      
        }

        Image img;
        string descriptionTop;
        string descriptionBottom;
        string full_path;

        public Image Img
        {
            get
            {
                return this.img;

            }
            set
            {
                this.img = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Img");
            }
        }

        public string DescriptionTop
        {
            get
            {
                return this.descriptionTop;
            }
            set
            {
                this.descriptionTop = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DescriptionTop");
            }
        }

        public string DescriptionBottom
        {
            get
            {
                return this.descriptionBottom;
            }
            set
            {
                this.descriptionBottom = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("DescriptionBottom");
            }
        }

        public string FullPath
        {
            get
            {
                return this.full_path;
            }
            set
            {
                this.full_path = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("FullPath");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string p_propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p_propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Представление:

```
<Window x:Class="Bind.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="Wind" 
        DataContext="myViewModel">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!--<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTemplate">
            <Image Source="{Binding Path=FullPath}"/>
        </DataTemplate>-->
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Images}"  
                 Background="Beige"
                 Width="{Binding ElementName=Wind, Path=Width}"
                 Height="{Binding ElementName=Wind, Path=Height}">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel/>  
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DescriptionTop}"/>   
                        <Image Height="65" Width="60" Source="{Binding Path=FullPath}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DescriptionBottom}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

View-Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.IO;

namespace Bind.view_model
{
    class MyViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public MyViewModel()
        {
            this.Images = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>();
            //this.images = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>();
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string p_propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(p_propertyName));
            }
        }

        ObservableCollection<MyImage> images;

        public ObservableCollection<MyImage> Images
        {
            get
            {
                images = new ObservableCollection<MyImage>();
                string[] dims = { "*.jpg", "*.png" };

                foreach (string mask in dims)
                {
                    string[] addresses = Directory.GetFiles(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), mask);
                    int i = 0;
                    foreach (string address in addresses)
                    {
                        i++;
                        images.Add(new MyImage(address, "image" + i.ToString(), ""));
                    }
                }

                return images;
            }
            set
            {
                images = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Images");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Картинки упорно не хотят отображаться. В чём же проблема?

Answer (score 4):

```
<Image Source="{Binding Img}" .../> : Img а не FullPath.
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2123244/wpf-listview-show-image/2123280#2123280